# Errorlevel is returning 0 but i can not set string variable using if

Tags: set, findstr, errorlevel

I am running DISM command and trying to find two strings in it and on finding the strings it should return Errorlevel 0. It is returning 0, and on getting a Errorlevel 0 i want to set a string variable value but i am not getting my results. Below is my code if someone can help.

```
     @echo off
     dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:install.wim /index:8 | Findstr "Professional x64"  >nul
     echo %ERRORLEVEL%
     PAUSE
     if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
     Set MYOS = "PROX64"
     )
     ECHO %MYOS%
     pause
```

Comment: This is Windows, not DOS. Fullstop. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dos/info

Comment: yes but this is a batch file

Comment: I didn't claim the opposite, but DOS is something completely different. Batch isn't automatically connected to DOS.

Comment: Ok buddy. I got your point..Thanks